# While creating instances, Cloud-init stops before creating the SSH keys

Tags: openstack, cloud-init

We have OpenStack v2.3.1, Mitaka with KVM installed on our cluster. While creating instances, the VMs are created successfully every time. However, Cloud-init randomly stops before creating SSH keys only on **a few of the instances** (this is not dependent on the node running the VM). Therefore, we cannot SSH to the created VM. This strangely does not leave any errors behind in the logs. Any idea what could cause this? Logs of working and non-working instances include below (The differences are at the end of the logs): Thank you.

[A log of NON-Working instance on gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/epezhman/b2f00c10a0fbcb52dda5931b5e2a95f1)

[A log of Working instance on gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/epezhman/8fdd27e600fbca05660f6df42e03cf1d)

Comment: Seems like the `cloud-init job` fails, though I'm not sure why this happens on some instances and works on others. So the ssh keys are not generated after cloud-init.

Comment: Are you able to see the cloudinit logs? If you can log on with a password, that would be the easiest way. Or make a copy of the failed instance's disk and use a libguestfs tool like `guestfish` to get those logs. The failed instance doesn't seem to log anything right after the start of cloud-init; I wonder if there is not a deeper problem there. By the way, 2.3.1 is the version of the OpenStack client, not of OpenStack. It's probably [Mitaka](https://docs.openstack.org/releasenotes/python-openstackclient/mitaka.html).